# Spawn instantiated objects in random positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to spawn multiple objects in random positions within some borders, but the objects are appearing too close to each other, and they are always appearing on the left side of the border.

This is the code I am using to spawn the objects (the words):

```
while (a < words2.Length)
{
    wordOutput = Instantiate(wordOutputPrefab) as GameObject;

    wordOutputPrefab.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshPro>().text = words2[a];

    wordOutputPrefab
        .GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshPro>()
        .GetComponentInChildren<RectTransform>()
        .position = new Vector3(
            UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 4),
            UnityEngine.Random.Range(-4, 4),
            0);

    a++;
}
```

And this is how the objects (the words) are appearing on the screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN7SG.png)

Comment: Have you tried increasing the values you pass to `Random.Range()`? Values like `4` seem rather small for such a big view.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to change the values multiple times, but the same thing happens.

Comment: Then maybe the range is a float between `0` and `1`. Have you tried `Range(0, 1)`?

Comment: I tried it, but still the same result. I'm not sure if the Random.Range is producing numbers that are close to each other, or if I am not correctly accessing the wordOutput objects.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride [`Range(0, 1)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) will always return `0` .. for `int` parameters it returns `int` values between `min` and `max - 1` ;)

Comment: I think the general issue might be: As soon as your texts are in a Canvas that is set to `Screenspace Overlay` the coordinates (position etc) are in **pixel space**!

Answer (score 0):

First of `UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 4);` will give you either 0, 1, 2, or 3. If you want to have floats you also need to give float values like this `UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 4f);`

Further more you should not use `.position` for RectTransforms but `.rect`, `.localposition` or `.anchoredPosition`.
What ever is the best really depends on how your Canvas and UI is structured!